# soap response to xml

Tags: python, web-services, suds

Consider the following soap response:

```
(ArrayOfNotificationData){NotificationData[] = (NotificationData){Id = 1 Title = "notification 1" Message = "bla bla." Published = 2000-01-01 00:00:00}, (NotificationData){Id = 2 Title = "notification 2" Message = "bla bla." Published = 2000-01-01 00:00:00},}
```

How can I convert this response to something like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetNotificationsResponse xmlns="http://localhost/WS.asmx">
        <GetNotificationsResult>
            <NotificationData>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <Title>notification 1</Title>
                <Message>bla bla.</Message>
                <Published>2000-01-01T00:00:00</Published>
            </NotificationData>
            <NotificationData>
                <Id>2</Id>
                <Title>notification 1</Title>
                <Message>bla bla.</Message>
                <Published>2001-01-01T00:00:00</Published>
            </NotificationData>
        </GetNotificationsResult>
    </GetNotificationsResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I'm using suds to call the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that regular expressions in a loop can be very mighty:

```
import re

s = '''(ArrayOfNotificationData){NotificationData[] = (NotificationData){Id = 1 Title = "notification 1" Message = "bla bla." Published = 2000-01-01 00:00:00}, (NotificationData){Id = 2 Title = "notification 2" Message = "bla bla." Published = 2000-01-01 00:00:00},}'''

def f(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v is None:
            d[k] = ''
    return d

def g(reg, rep):
    c1 = s
    c2 = ''
    while c1 != c2:
        c2 = c1
        c1 = re.sub(reg, lambda m: rep.format(**f(m.groupdict())), c1)
    print c1

g('(?P<m>\w+)\s+=\s+(?:(?P<v>\\d+-\\d+-\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+|\w+)|"(?P<v3>[^"]*)")|(?:(?:\\w|\\[|\\])+\\s*=\\s*)?\\((?P<m2>\w+)\\){(?P<v2>[^}{]*)}\s*,?', '<{m}{m2}>{v}{v2}{v3}</{m}{m2}>')
```

And the Result is: (just without formatting)

```
<ArrayOfNotificationData>

    <NotificationData>

        <Id>1</Id> 
        <Title>notification 1</Title> 
        <Message>bla bla.</Message> 
        <Published>2000-01-01 00:00:00</Published>

    </NotificationData> 
    <NotificationData>

        <Id>2</Id> 
        <Title>notification 2</Title> 
        <Message>bla bla.</Message> 
        <Published>2000-01-01 00:00:00</Published>

    </NotificationData>

</ArrayOfNotificationData>
```

Unformatted:

```
<ArrayOfNotificationData><NotificationData><Id>1</Id> <Title>notification 1</Title> <Message>bla bla.</Message> <Published>2000-01-01 00:00:00</Published></NotificationData> <NotificationData><Id>2</Id> <Title>notification 2</Title> <Message>bla bla.</Message> <Published>2000-01-01 00:00:00</Published></NotificationData></ArrayOfNotificationData>
```

I like this very much. Otherwise I would not have created this solution.
If you want to use regex replacement for contextfree grammars you have to be careful.

Btw: If there is a `}` or `{` in the code between the `""` this will not work: `Title = "notification} 1"`
If you need help on this, too, write a comment :)